# Prove or refute: If dom(r) = ran(r) = A then r ⊆ A x A.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My question is how to prove or refute this claim.
It's stated as: If dom(r) = ran(r) = A then r ⊆  A x A.
I have worked out an example for this so far, (where it appears to be true) but not a proof, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks very much.

Comment: domain and range are not be completely standard terms across different authors. So it would be helpful to give the definition you are given of those. (Also you forget to state that $r$ was a relation in the first place.)

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything to prove.  Isn't that simply a consequence of definition.  If (a,b) in r, then a in Dom r and b in ran (r) so (a,b) in AxA.  What's to prove?

Answer (score 2):

Look up your definitions for $\operatorname{dom} (r)$ and $\operatorname{ran}(r)$  They should be something like the domain is the set of first elements of the relation or a set to which all the first elements of the relation belong.  The range should be the same for second elements.  So take an arbitrary element of $r, (a,b)$  Argue that $a \in A, b \in A,$ so $(a,b) \in A \times A$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,y) \in r$ and $r$ be a graph, for hypothesis the $dom r$ is: 
$$(\exists y)(x,y)\in r$$
$\implies$ For hypothesis $domr \subseteq ranr$
$$(\exists x)(x,y) \in r$$
$\implies$ By the law of conjunction
$$x \in r \land y \in r$$
$\implies$For hypothesis $domr \subseteq ranr \subseteq A$
$$x \in A \land y \in A$$
$\implies$For definition of Cartesian product
$$(x,y) \in A \times A$$
Then, $r \subseteq A \times A$ $\blacksquare$

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $\operatorname{dom}(R)$ is defined as $\{x:\exists y,(x,y)\in R\}$ and $\operatorname{ran}(R)=\{y:\exists x,(x,y)\in R\}$.

The statement is false unless you assume $R$ is a relation, i.e. a subset of $V\times V$, or a set which only contains elements of the form $(x,y)$ for some sets $x,y$. For example, the ordinal $1=\{\emptyset\}$ does not contain any (Kuratowski) ordered pair $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ for any choice of $a,b$, because $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}\ne\emptyset$. Thus $\operatorname{dom}(1)=\operatorname{ran}(1)=\emptyset$ but $1\not\subseteq\emptyset\times\emptyset=\emptyset$.

If $R$ is a relation, then the statement is true. Let $z\in R$ be arbitrary; since $R$ is a relation it is of the form $z=(x,y)$. Then $x\in\operatorname{dom}(R)$ (since $\exists y',(x,y')\in R$) and $y\in\operatorname{ran}(R)$ (since $\exists x',(x',y)\in R$), so $z=(x,y)\in \operatorname{dom}(R)\times\operatorname{ran}(R)$. Thus $R\subseteq \operatorname{dom}(R)\times\operatorname{ran}(R)$.

Comment: Yes, r is a relation here. Thanks for the proof!